# ¿Los títulos de tablas y figuras llevan punto?

Tags: redacción

¿Existe una fuente de información confiable que diga si los títulos de tablas y figuras de un trabajo de investigación llevan punto al final o si no lo llevan?

Por ejemplo: Tabla 2.1. Clasificación de los seres vivos(.)

He visto que muchos blogs que dicen que sí y otros tantos que dicen que no deben terminar con punto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La *Ortografía 2010* de la RAE [parece dejarlo bien claro](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=heskPUYgWggLzJlD) en el punto 3.4.1.2, en caso de que no dispongas de una guía de estilo:

> Nunca se escribe punto tras los títulos y subtítulos de libros, artículos, capítulos, obras de arte, etc., cuando aparecen aislados (centrados o no) y son el único texto del renglón.
>
> Tampoco se escriben con punto final los títulos y cabeceras de cuadros y tablas.

Un poco más adelante, especifica:

> Los textos que aparecen bajo ilustraciones, fotografías, diagramas, etc., dentro de un libro o una publicación periódica no suelen cerrarse con punto cuando constituyen etiquetas que describen el contenido de dichas imágenes [...].
>
> Como en el caso de las dedicatorias, cuanto más extenso es el texto que constituye un pie de imagen, tanto mayor es la tendencia a la escritura del punto final, especialmente cuando dicho texto presenta puntuación interna. [...]
>
> Cuando los pies de imagen no son propiamente etiquetas, sino explicaciones de carácter discursivo que suelen tener estructura oracional, deben cerrarse con punto.

Así pues, yo entiendo que los títulos de cuadros y tablas no llevan punto final. Ahora bien, puedes considerar el apartado dedicado a los títulos descriptivos de imágenes. Si vas a poner un texto largo y explicativo, tal vez debas cerrar con puntos los títulos. Si solo son etiquetas o descripciones breves, no los pongas. En todo caso, pienso que lo importante es que seas constante y lo hagas siempre de la misma forma. Los lectores no van a considerar si según la RAE poner un punto final es o no es correcto en los títulos de las tablas, pero sí se pueden extrañar si demuestras una falta de coherencia en la redacción del artículo (si a veces pones el punto y a veces no). A fin de cuentas, si no tienes coherencia en la redacción, ¿quién dice que la hayas tenido durante el desarrollo de la investigación?

Answer (score 6):

La Real Academia Española publica en línea un "diccionario panhispánico de dudas" (DPD), disponible en esta liga http://lema.rae.es/dpd/. En él, específicamente en la sección pertinente al punto (http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=PxrAnmVfND6FK0uGdT), se explican sus usos correctos e incorrectos. Entre los incorrectos, el punto 5.4 establece

> 5.4. Nunca se escribe punto tras los títulos y subtítulos de libros, artículos, capítulos, obras de arte, etc., cuando aparecen aislados y
>   son el único texto del renglón:
>
> Cien años de soledad
>
> Tampoco llevan punto al final los nombres de autor en cubiertas,
>   portadas, prólogos, firmas de cartas y otros documentos, o en
>   cualquier otra ocasión en que aparezcan solos en un renglón.

No se especifica el uso en títulos de tablas y figuras. Sin embargo, se puede argumentar que, ya que este uso no corresponde a ninguno de los casos de uso correcto descritos y es similar al uso en títulos en libros y capítulos, el uso de punto después de un título de este tipo es incorrecto de acuerdo al DPD.

De cualquier manera, sugiero que revises si la institución que publicará tu trabajo de investigación emite una guía de estilo. Si es así, ésta debería ser la autoridad máxima en el uso de puntuación en tu trabajo.

Comment: @walen Muchas gracias.